# What does "gclid" in some URL's mean?

Tags: code

I find in some URL's something called "gclid" composed of bunch of numeric and alphabetic letters but what does it mean? For example, i found it in this link:

> `http://www.abebooks.com/Habits-Highly-Effective-People-Powerful-Lessons/11872225811/bd?cm_mmc=gmc-_-new-_-PLA-_-v01&cm_mmc=ggl-_-US_AbeBooks_PLA_Retargeting-_--_-&gclid=CK-0v-Pwts8CFYOZvAodT6EDLg`

Comment: One note: items appearing in a url after the ? are known as the "query string", and is a list of name/value pairs separated by &.  You are quite correct that this particular variable name has a common meaning, but it is important to understand that the var name is arbitrary from the site developers perspective. I could use the var `gclid` to mean 'Global Class ID` and use an entirely differant value for an entirely differant purpose, so unless there is some nexus, its not safe to assume that all instances of "gclid" are in any way the same.

Answer (score 5):

Gclid is a globally unique tracking parameter (Google Click Identifier) used by Google to pass information back and forth between Google AdWords and Google Analytics. If you enable URL auto tagging in Google AdWords, Google will append a unique? gclid parameter on your destination URLs at run-time.

**EDIT:**

BD? = is some form of url encoding.

CM_MMC These tags get appended to the end of links, using the format cm_mmc=A-*-B-*-C-_-D.  As shown, there are four slots available.  They are usually used as Vendor, Category, Placement, and Item but this can be changed on however you like. This is usually a way to track marketing campaigns with coremetrics

Comment: Also there is two more parameters in the same link, which appears as "bd?cm_mmc=gmc-_-new-_-PLA-_-v01&cm_mmc=ggl-_-US_AbeBooks_PLA_Retargeting-_--_-"  What does these two parameter means?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: BD is the name of the page\document. the server uses some form of request router (as you might expect in an MVC site) so it does not end in a file extension. the ? separates the path to the document from the query-string parameters being passed to the server so it can render the document.

Comment: @Dylan Rz I tried to notify you by mentioning ur name at the beginning but couldn't but pleasure u got the above comment though. One more query Dylan!

Comment: @Dylan Rz I encountered the link initially when i searched for "audiobook" in Google then i went to the page [about.com](http://mp3.about.com/od/glossary/g/Audiobooks-Definition-What-Are-Audiobooks.htm) . At the right side of page there were couple display ads and when I hover over the ad _Seven Habits of Highly Effectve People_ the URL appeared bottom left corner of the PC. The link is  as `www.googleadservice.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=(long chain of alphanumeric)`. what does _aclk?sa=L&ai_ mean?